# Redirect one domain to another domain and all to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I'm already working since hours on it. There's always something that doesn't work.

I have two domains `example.com` and `example.de`.

I want to redirect all from `example.com` to `example.de` and set `https://www`.

After redirected I want to have ALWAYS `https://www.example.de` (`https` and `www` and the `de` domain).

The following need to get redirected to `https://www.example.de`:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.de
http://www.example.de
https://example.de
```

Is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.de%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same as the OP, with a .co.uk and a .com The solution above works for most cases, but not for https on the .co.uk, with or without a leading www.

Comment: @RichHarding Add a new question because it's hard for me to answer here

Comment: it's fine, I understand why it's not possible now - it'd violate SSL if it worked.